# How do I transfer data between sheets in reference to columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

new to google sheets so help would be appreciated.

I have a sheet with column 5 header “userid” and column 6 header “date”. The userid column is full of randomly generated id numbers and the date column is empty.
I have a second sheet with the same 2 columns, however the user ids are in a different order and the date column is full with dates associated with the ids.

How do I pull the dates from sheet 2 into sheet 1 but have the dates match up with the userid as in sheet 2.
Copy/paste won’t work as the userid’s are in different orders on the 2 sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use vlookup in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; Sheet1!A:B; 2; 0)))
```

where column A holds ID and column B holds date

---

[image]

Comment: That’s great thanks! Will this pull across from 2 separate sheets? Do I need to put the sheet names in the formula?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheets?

Comment: I will create an example, do I paste the URL in here?

Comment: Thanks! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1096GA5-rV0zxKlO0ua1aRn8U491EGkV98MrSZnAgThc/edit

That should work

Comment: Can you explain what “2” and “0” does in the formula?

Comment: 2 is second column from range A:B and 0 stands for "exact match"